# Photon number conservation during scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, scattering, thermal-radiation

I was reading [this](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/home/kblum/IPC/tutorial%20notes/TutKfirSZ.pdf) writeup on the Kompaneets equation and the Sunyaev-Zel'dovich effect.

On page 3, section 2 the author states

> There is no way to increase the mean energy of a planckian distribution without changing the particle number.

But as far as I understand, photon number is conserved during a scattering process, and therefore isn't it possible that for a given Planckian distribution all the photons gain the same energy through scattering and thus increase the mean energy of the Planckian distribution? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Planckian distribution is a thermal distribution. If you change the energy distribution of the photons, then they are not at equilibrium with the environment. So that won't work. You have to change the temperature of the system, and that will change the mean number of photons.